# Obj-c IOS Memory Management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

**Question #1**: As a rule, I never release an object if I don't have to. Assuming that stringWithUTF8String has an autorelease inside itself, I don't have to do "return [... autorelease]", right?

```
-(NSString*)nonNullDBString:(const unsigned char*)value {
if(value == nil) {
    return @"";
} else {
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)value];
}
```

}

**Question #2**: In my class I have the attribute: "const uint8_t *bytes;". In the dealloc method must I call "bytes = nil;" or "free(bytes);", or nothing at all?

**Question #3**: For @property(nonatomic, retain) variables in my classes, what is the best practice of dealloc'ing, is it "self.foo = nil;" or "**[foo releease] (what I am doing now)**". Additionally, I do not want to mess with KVO issues, whatever they are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1) Right. Your snippet is correct.

A2) If you `malloc`'ed it then call `free` (it's a C after all). No need to do `foo = nil` - your object will be dead upon return from `dealloc`, nobody cares what this pointer value is anymore.

A3) `[foo release];` .

Comment: All correct answers, yet there are a lot of people arguing about the exclusive correctness of answer number 3. For myself, I went with the argument that by consistently using `self.foo = nil` on all writable (retained/assign) pointer properties, you can be fairly sure no memory management rules are broken. I heard, though can't verify that even the Apple people do it this way nowadays.